# C code doesn't give expected answer when using macros for multiplication and addition

Tags: c, function, macros

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#define sum(x,y) x+y
#define f(x,y) sum(x,y)*2
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float m=6,n=1;
    int x= f(m,n);
    printf("x is %d\n",x);  
}
```

I get the answer for x as 8.How is this possible.

Comment: ... `x + y * 2`

Comment: Macros works basically like copy-pasting text.

Comment: This is basically a school book example which you'll find in any C book, where it explains that function-like macros and macro parameters must always be surrounded with parenthesis. Correctly written it would be `#define sum(x,y) ((x)+(y))`, as explained in any C book.

Comment: ALWAYS put macro parameters inside parentheses...

Comment: Simple solution: Don't use function-like macros, use *actual* functions.

Answer (score 2):

The macros would resolve to `6 + 1 * 2`. Macros are a direct text replacement mechanism.

First the compiler would do `sum(x,y)*2` and then `x+y*2`.

Macros are not functions but direct text replacements.
If you add a lot of brackets everything will be fine regardless of how/what you substitute with the macro.

`#define sum(x,y) ((x)+(y))`

Answer (score 1):

I find it helpful to look at the code after it's being expanded by the macro processor.  With gcc it would cpp your_file.c:

```
...

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float m=6,n=1;
    int x= m+n*2;
    printf("x is %d\n",x);
}
```

So your macro should be:

```
#define sum(x,y) (x+y)
```

or even better:

```
#define sum(x,y) ((x)+(y))
```